# Разница между «ослабеть» и «ослабнуть»

Tags: синонимы

Понятно, что это синонимы. Но есть ли между ними разница в значении или в употреблении? Например

> Она ослабла/ослабела от голода.

Что лучше? Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

В словаре словообразовательных частиц Ефремовой указано, что **суффикс НУ в глаголах обозначает постепенное усиление признака**, а суффикс Е имеет **общее** значение **приобретения призна**ка.

Если речь идет о физической слабости, то, возможно, выбор формы зависит от контекста: а) не ела пару дней и ослабела от голода; б) недоедала долгое время и ослабла от голода.

А вообще говоря, прилагательное "слабый" **многозначное,** например, струна может быть натянута слабо. Тогда говорят: **струна ослабла, а не ослабела.** Поэтому надо учитывать конкретную ситуацию, не всегда эти глаголы заменяют друг друга.

**Примеры:**

Я болел, а больной **ослабел** от голода. [Варлам Шаламов]

Он почувствовал, как вдруг **сразу ослабел** от голода, от бессонной ночи в машине, от всего того, что ему пришлось сейчас пережить… [Вадим Кожевников]

Но он уже так **ослаб от голода,** что не мог подняться на ноги и высунуть голову из дупла. [В. В. Бианки. Лесные были и небылицы (1923-1958)]

Comment: Похоже, с неодушевленными сушествительными только "ослабла", а с одушевленными – оба. Чувствую, что от степени еще зависит, как вы считаете? Если совсем, то что, ослабла? Ослабела?

Comment: Она уже старенькая была, давным-давно на пенсии, а в ту осень резко ослабла. [Эдуард Русаков, 2013] Когда ослабла, наняла женщину, Анну Ивановну [Александр Терехов. (1997-2008)] Это примеры из Нацкорпуса. Другие варианты: рука ослабла, воля ослабла, хватка ослабла, валюта ослабла. Возможно, с неодуш. сущ. сочетаемость без ограничений, а для физического состояния делается выбор. Другой пример: ветер ослаб - 5 примеров, ветер ослабел - 8 примеров. Поэтому общую картину с учетом  влияния различных факторов определить не так просто.